# Python get JSON Data from File - AttributeErrors for 'str' object

Tags: python, json

In my program I have command: `info = json.load("file.txt")`

Program returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path-to-program", line 17, in <module>
    info = json.load("file.txt")
  File "***\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

This is JSON File from which I want to get data:

```
 {
        "40990": {
            "name": "Mafia",
            "capsule": "https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/40990/header_292x136.jpg?t=1568743837",
            "review_score": 8,
            "review_desc": "Very Positive",
            "reviews_total": "4,337",
            "reviews_percent": 91,
            "release_date": null,
            "type": "Game",
            "review_css": "positive",
            "priority": 19,
            "added": 1595054913,
            "rank": 1000,
            "is_free_game": false,
            "win": 1
        }
 }
```

---

Another problem - after modifying this program I want to print keys() (should print `"40990"`)

But Program returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path-to-program", line 22, in <module>
    keylist = info.keys()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problems are because you aren't passing in a valid object:

```
info = json.load("file.txt")
```

`file.txt` in your case is just seen as a string, hence *"'str' object has no attribute 'read'"* and *"'str' object has no attribute 'keys'"*.

You need to pass an IO / file into the `json.load()`, e.g.:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

*or*

```
file = open('file.txt')
data = json.load(file)
```

For **further reading** purposes I highly suggest [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 1):

`json.load` doesn't work like you expect it to work. You need to specify a file pointer there, not a string (filename). See [json documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Example code to show how to handle files, rather than strings

```py
import json

with open("file.txt") as f:
    info = json.load(f)
    print(info) # should print your parsed json
```

Comment: This solves my problems! Thanks a lot! :D